# Add script just after <head>

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I'm registering to Google AdSense. In order to check the site they want that I put a piece of code inside (`<script>something</script>`) just after `<head>` tag.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is Joomla's version and what template are you using?

Comment: Joomla 3.5 and the template is Cloudbase3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, according to the [docs](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181950?hl=en-GB) AdSense code doesn't go after the `<head>`, it goes between the `<body>` tags. JavaScript should almost always be placed at the end of the body, just before `</body>`, so slow-loading scripts don't hold up the rest of your page (in this case, however, the script is loaded asynchronously so that shouldn't be much of an issue. Still, Google's docs have it at the bottom of the body and it's considered best practice to put any external scripts there, so that's what I'd do).

You want to add the script to the index.php of the site template(s) you'll be using. If I was using the default Protostar template, for example, I'd edit `.../templates/protostar/index.php` like so (I've used the same script code from the docs I linked to above, replace that with your own AdSense code):

```
    </footer>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="none" />

    // AdSense code begins:
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
    data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    // AdSense code ends.

</body>
```

Do the equivalent for your Cloudbase3 template and it should hopefully work for you.